# Connecting Cytoscape to external server

Tags: cytoscape

I want to create and host a file on a remote server and allow cytoscape to poll it every time it starts up to see if there are any changes. I'm not sure where to even start with that. Was hoping I might get some information here.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's pretty easy.  As part of your app initialization in your CyActivator, you could easily poll your remote site.  The CyActivator start method gets called when Cytoscape starts up (or you app changes).  I would strongly suggest that you do your poll in a separate thread since Cytoscape won't actually start until your start method returns...

Comment: Oh hey that's pretty neat. Couple of questions:
1) is that supported with the desktop app
2) what parms do I use with getMyNetwork() to grab it from my external server? (im guessing that's the one I need). would it be my.domain.com getMyNetwork()?

Comment: It's definitely supported with the desktop app (I thought that's what you were referring to).  getMyNetwork() isn't part of the desktop API, so I can't comment on that.  If it's a network you want to poll, there are lots of examples of how to pull in a network -- you can look at the source to the stringApp or intActApp or the wikiPathways app as examples.

Comment: Yes, i'm using the desktop version. I have a file located on a webserver, but when I try to pull it from there (import table from url. This is a csv file) I get "could not open stream for reader error"